# Language Agnostic Name for C# "usings" or VB "imports"

Tags: language-agnostic, naming

What is the proper or most appropriate language agnostic name for C#'s "using" and VB's "Imports"?

- alias
- namespace
- include
- reference

or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refer to this as a *"module inclusion"* feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing package. You have the same in Java.

You can say you're using/importing a package. I'd say all the rest are quite different.

Comment: package sounds more Java specific than it does language agnostic, but thanks for the suggestion.  I agree my other suggestions aren't very good, though.